# How to write data of streaming query to Hive?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am reading data from HDFS using Spark Structured Streaming. I want to save that dataFrame to Hive.

I have done like this but it giving error.

```
totalSalary.write.format("csv").mode("append").saveAsTable("test")
```

[image: i am geeting below error]

Comment: Can you provide your error stack ?

Comment: You generally write the stream to storage and create a table on it

Comment: I updated the question with error image.@rbcvl

Answer (score 0):

`totalySalary` is not a `Dataframe`but a `DStream` ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/api/streaming/spark/streaming/DStream.html)). The method `write` doesn't exist for this class.

There is a good example here : 
[How to read stream of structured data and write to Hive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56257065/how-to-read-stream-of-structured-data-and-write-to-hive-table)

```
val query = totalSalary.writeStream.foreachBatch((batchDs: Dataset[_], batchId: Long) => {
         batchDs.write
         .mode(append)
         .insertInto("test");
}).start()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is it possible to perform this operation in pyspark.@rbcvl

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Spark Structured Streaming does not support saving the result of a streaming query to Hive.

---

As the error says, `totalSalary` is a streaming dataframe and supports `writeStream` only.

The main issue is that you cannot write out the result of a streaming query to a Hive table. It is simply not supported (there is no method `saveAsTable` or similar on `DataStreamWriter`).